# Form response file upload

Tags: c#, sitefinity

In sitefinity, My form contains a file upload control. How do I set the file upload value to the files that have been selected? I am trying to set the values of the form programmatically. Below is what I have so far:

```
 //Enquiry Test
                entry.SetValue("FormParagraphTextBox_C007", "Test sample");
                int count = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    var file = Request.Files[i];
                    var contentTtype = Request.Files[i].ContentType;

                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();

                    if (ValidFileFormats.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Contains(extension))
                    {
                        MIMETypeChecker mc = new MIMETypeChecker();
                        if (contentTtype == mc.GetMIMEType(file.FileName))
                        {
                            byte[] fileBytes;
                            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
                            {
                                fileBytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[i].ContentLength);
                            }

                            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnquiriesUploadPath"] + Member.MemberNumber + "/" + refNrNe.ReferenceNumber);
                            if (!dir.Exists)
                                dir.Create();

                            if (dir.GetFiles().Count() < 11)
                            {
                                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(dir.FullName + "/" + file.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                                {
                                    fs.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);                                       
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Attatchment Upload
                entry.SetValue("FormFileUpload_C008", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the value of the upload control as this would be a huge security vulnerability. Only the user can select which file is to be uploaded.

Comment: The user is selecting the files.Hence the 'Request.Files' I am now starting to think this might be my best option. [link](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/developing-with-sitefinity-/how-to-programmatically-associate-document-upload-to-form-response-entry)

Answer (score 0):

For programmatically attaching file to form response, you need to use ContentLink's
Short example how to do that:

```
    void CreateFormResponse()
    {
        FormsManager formsMgr = FormsManager.GetManager();
        formsMgr.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;

        var form = formsMgr.GetFormByName("sf_stackoverflow");

        if (form != null)
        {
            var entryType = String.Format("{0}.{1}", formsMgr.Provider.FormsNamespace, form.Name);
            FormEntry entry = formsMgr.CreateFormEntry(entryType);

            //here you can populate text fields
            entry.SetValue("FormTextBox_C001", "fieldvalue");


            var documentContentLinks = UploadDocument(entry);
            entry.SetValue("FormFileUpload_C003", documentContentLinks);
            entry.IpAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
            entry.SubmittedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            entry.UserId = ClaimsManager.GetCurrentUserId();
            if (SystemManager.CurrentContext.AppSettings.Multilingual)
            {
                entry.Language = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name;
            }

            entry.ReferralCode = formsMgr.Provider.GetNextReferralCode(entryType).ToString();

            formsMgr.SaveChanges();
        }

    }

    ContentLink[] UploadDocument(FormEntry entry)
    {
        LibrariesManager libraryManager = LibrariesManager.GetManager();
        var contentLinksManager = ContentLinksManager.GetManager();

        //here you need to choose proper document, or upload your document
        var document = libraryManager.GetDocuments().FirstOrDefault();

        ContentLink contentLink = new ContentLink();
        contentLink.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        contentLink.ParentItemId = entry.Id;
        contentLink.ParentItemType = entry.GetType().ToString();
        contentLink.ChildItemId = document.Id;
        contentLink.ComponentPropertyName = entry.Id.ToString();
        contentLink.ChildItemAdditionalInfo = "additional info";
        contentLink.ChildItemProviderName = (((IDataItem)document).Provider as DataProviderBase).Name;
        contentLink.ChildItemType = document.GetType().FullName;
        contentLink.ApplicationName = contentLinksManager.Provider.ApplicationName;

        ContentLink[] contentLinks = new ContentLink[0];
        if (contentLinks == null)
        {
            contentLinks = new ContentLink[0];
        }

        var assetsFieldList = contentLinks.ToList();
        assetsFieldList.Insert(0, contentLink);
        return assetsFieldList.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: But how to upload multiple files?

Comment: In my example UploadDocument is returning array of content links. If you need multiple documents, then add it to this array

Comment: Yes I added multiple elements in array but when I called "entry.SetValue("FormFileUpload_C003", documentContentLinks);" method, it produced error. So, I just skipped creating "assetsFieldList" list and directly appended contentlink elements to contentLinks array then passed it to the "entry.SetValue("FormFileUpload_C003", documentContentLinks);" method then it worked fine.